# bash [-+]O shopt_name doesn't work the way it's supposed to as per by the manual

Tags: bash

The bash manual says:

"

```
  [-+]O [shopt_option]
          shopt_option is one of the shell options accepted by the
          shopt builtin (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).  If
          shopt_option is present, -O sets the value of that option;
          +O unsets it.  If shopt_option is not supplied, the names
          and values of the shell options accepted by shopt are
          printed on the standard output.  If the invocation option
          is +O, the output is displayed in a format that may be
          reused as input.
```

"

However, suppose I have the extglob option set on my current instance of bash by default. Now, if I invoke a new instance of bash by doing `bash +O extglob`, extglob is still set for the new instance; it doesn't get unset for the new instance. However, if I now run  `shopt -u extglob` in the new instance, then extglob WILL get unset.

So, what's going on here? Why doesn't the `bash [-+]O opt_name` have an effect?

The only wild guess I have to this problem is that maybe when I run `bash +O extglob`, it initially *bootstraps* bash with extglob off, but then bash *boots up* reading all the config files and then it enables all the shopt options which are supposed to be on by default; like extglob. Thus re-enabliing extglob even though it was disabled initially.

Comment: I concur with your hypothesis (your setting is changed by rc files). Why don't you verify it with `bash --norc +O extglob`?

Comment: @xhienne Yeah, I just did that and it proved my hypothesis. So I guess that's it then. However, this leads to another question... where exactly is extglob being set? From the looks of it, if we disable the rc file, then extglob doesnt get set. So that means it's being set in the rc file. But I tried looking for it in the rc file and couldn't find it, so where is it?

Comment: @The_Weeping_One On my Debian system it's enabled in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` which is sourced at the end of my `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @Freddy I see. Thanks.